# javascript form validation with multiple if statements

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement

is this form validation function correct? or it can be done better ? 
For example: I want one of the two drop-downs to have a value before checking the contact details fields, (dp1 OR dp2) but even though using ( || ) the validation is acting as &&.

```
$('#send').click(function(){

if( document.downloadForm.SoftwareDp.value == "0" || document.downloadForm.ManualDp.value == "0" )
{
 alert( "Please Select a file for Download" );
 return false;  }

// First check if Dropdown 1 OR dropdown 2 have been selected ( ONE at least)


if( document.downloadForm.name.value == "" && document.downloadForm.email.value == "" )
{
 alert( "Please enter your details" );
 return false;  }

 // then check if name and email are typed in.

 else{ // run some ajax if above conditions are met } });
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/UGotAFIL/1/edit?html,js,output
Thanks

Comment: Why do you compare the values with 0 in the first if ?

Comment: You could use jquery validation plugin for form validation. It will more easy use. http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: First default option <option value="0">Software</option> ect... then other options have value...

Comment: Take a look at this http://jsbin.com/IRiCases/1/edit why do you think that || is acting like a && ? it works fine.

Comment: @tiberiu.corbu, Thanks, but it is not. check the edited version...

Comment: You check if one of them is not selected and than output an error. I think you should check if both of them are not selected, which is equivalent to not one of them is selected.

Comment: @user3003977 could you give me the link ?

Comment: @user3003977 refer this link http://jsbin.com/agIQEKiL/1/edit

Comment: @user3003977 if you need to select at least one drop down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition working perfectly.
If you want to check both drop down are not selected you should use `&&` instead of `||`.

If you need to select at least one drop down means you can you can use

```
 $('#send').click(function(){

if(!( document.downloadForm.SoftwareDp.value != "0" || document.downloadForm.ManualDp.value != "0" ))
{
 alert( "Please Select a file for Download" );
 return false;  }

// First check if Dropdown 1 OR dropdown 2 have been selected ( ONE at least)


if( document.downloadForm.name.value === "" && document.downloadForm.email.value === "" )
{
 alert( "Please enter your details" );
 return false;  }

 // then check if name and email are typed in.

 else{ // run some ajax if above conditions are met 
 } });
```

see this jsbin [demo](http://jsbin.com/agIQEKiL/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show the error when no dropdown has a value, that is both have no value.
Change

```
if( document.downloadForm.SoftwareDp.value == "0" || document.downloadForm.ManualDp.value == "0" )
```

to either

```
if( document.downloadForm.SoftwareDp.value == "0" && document.downloadForm.ManualDp.value == "0" ) // both have the default value 0
```

or

```
if(!( document.downloadForm.SoftwareDp.value != "0" || document.downloadForm.ManualDp.value != "0" )) // none of them has not the default value
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are checking will always give alert unless you select other than 0 values in both.

You should do it this way:

```
if( document.downloadForm.SoftwareDp.value == "0" && document.downloadForm.ManualDp.value == "0" )
```

The above will give alert only when both are selected for 0. If one of them has other value it won't display alert.